# Using Javascript to calculate Form fields with a combination of radio buttons, text fields, and a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function baseCalculate(slider,sqft,plumbing,credit){
    var cost = document.getElementById("cost");
    var slideval = document.getElementById("slideval");
    var sqft = document.getElementById("sqft");
    var plumbing = document.getElementsByName("plumbing");
    var credit = document.getElementsByName("Credit");
    var price = slider;
    cost.innerHTML = "$"+(((sqft * price) + plumbing) * credit);
    slideval.innerHTML = slider;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Job Estimator</h2>
How many square feet? 
<input type="text" id="sqft"><br>
Price per Square Foot? <input type="range" min="55" max="80" value="70" step="1 
onChange="baseCalculate(this.value,'sqft','plumbing','Credit')" style="width:500px;">

<span id="slideval">70</span>
<p>
 <legend>Will there be plumbing?</legend> <label>
    <input type="radio" name="plumbing" value="150" id="plumbing_0">
    yes</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="plumbing" value="0" id="plumbing_1">
    no</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="plumbing" value="-150" id="plumbing_2">
    promo</label>
  <br>
</p>
<p><legend>Paying with credit card?</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="Credit" value="1.06" id="Credit_0">
    Yes</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="Credit" value="1" id="Credit_1">
    No</label>
  <br>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" name="Credit" value=".94" id="Credit_2">
    Promo</label>
  <br>
</p>
<h2>This is the cost of the project: <span id="cost"></span></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I am using. I am trying to get it to multiply the sqft times the price then add on the plumbing and then multiply all that by the credit.

What am I missing here? It returns a NaN.

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the text value using **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.textContent)** and perform a calculation

```
var cost = document.getElementById("cost").textContent;
var slideval = document.getElementById("slideval").textContent;
var sqft = document.getElementById("sqft").textContent;
```

and also **value** for input element

```
var plumbing = document.getElementsByName("plumbing")[0].value;
var credit = document.getElementsByName("Credit")[0].value;
```

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) will return the array and here i took the first value `[0]`

Your case you need to do a for loop and check for `checked` attribute and get its `value` for calculation